# Cross product of two collections using the Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, cross-product

I have two lists:

```
List<Integer> list1 = ...
List<Integer> list2 = ...
```

I have the following class:

```
class Pair {
    public Pair(final Integer i1, final Integer i2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible with Java8 streams to combine the two input lists to a `List<Pair>`? This can be easily done with a double for-loop, but I am wondering if this is possible with Java8 streams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list1.stream()
     .flatMap(i1 -> list2.stream()
                         .map(i2 -> new Pair(i1, i2)))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```