# How to do a row first traversal of a list of lists of the same length using IntStream

Tags: java, java-stream, tostring

I have some [working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674200/1493294) that turns this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Columns()
        .addLine("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
        .addLine("1", "2", "3", "4")
        .print()
    ;
}
```

into this:

```
One Two Three Four 
1   2   3     4
```

but while trying to improve it with [this also working code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284061/40367), and follow the advice given about it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284234/40367), I tried to replace this working `toString()` code:

```
public String toString(){
    
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final int rows = columns.get(0).size();

    IntStream
        .range(0, rows)
        .forEach( 
            row -> {
                result
                    .append( 
                        columns
                        .stream()
                        .map(col -> col.getCell(row))
                        .collect( Collectors.joining(columnSeparator) )
                    )
                ;
                result.append( System.lineSeparator() );
            }
        )
    ;

    return result.toString();
}
```

with this broken `toString()` code:  <sup>[was following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32296261/1493294)</sup>

```
public String toString(){
    
    final int rows = columns.get(0).size();
    
    return IntStream
        .range(0, rows)
        .flatMap(row -> columns
            .stream()
            .map( col -> col.getCell(row) )
            .collect( Collectors.joining(columnSeparator) )
        )
        .collect( Collectors.joining( System.lineSeparator() ) )
    ;
}
```

only to see this:

```
Columns.java:81: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
                .collect( Collectors.joining(columnSeparator) )
                        ^
    inference variable R has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: String
      lower bounds: IntStream,Object
  where R,A,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
    A extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

to which I can only say, rats.

---

If you're the kind that hates clicking links here's the highlights of what you're missing:

```
private final List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
```

And down in the `Column` class we find

```
public String getCell(int row){
    return padCell( words.get(row), maxLength );
}
```

The advise I was given: "replace the `StringBuilder` in toString with another joining `Collector`."

The `toString` is trying to traverse these columns row by row concatenating the padded cells of strings it finds in each. Completing a row of cells from all columns before going to the next row.

Yes I know a simple double for loop can do this but where's the fun in that?

<sup>Honestly it works but leaves unneeded column separators hanging on the side which bugs me</sup>

Comment: StringBuilder is declared but not used in the replacement.  But anyway, what is the expected output and what is `getCell()`?  Showing some sample data with any classes, if they exist, would help.

Comment: `flatMap()` expects a stream. You're returning a single string. Maybe just try `map()`?

Comment: @shmosel blindly turning flatMap into map does not banish the rats.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Well, I didn't say blindly. Looks like you actually need `mapToObj()`.

Comment: @shmosel Hey, whada know. Blindly turning `flatMap` into `mapToObj` banished the rats. Thanks. Consider writing it up as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer stream calls `flatMap()` which is supposed to expand each element into a stream (in this case, `IntStream`) and flatten the results back into one stream. It's failing because the provided fuction returns a single string instead of a stream. Since the result is one-for-one, you just need an ordinary map operation to transform each row into a string:

```
return IntStream
    .range(0, rows)
    .mapToObj(row -> columns
        .stream()
        .map( col -> col.getCell(row) )
        .collect( Collectors.joining(columnSeparator) )
    )
    .collect( Collectors.joining( System.lineSeparator() ) )
;
```

Comment: Incorporated your answer into [this code review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284284/40367)